# Using CSS "layout-grid-type:Fixed" to mix Japanese and English text

Tags: css, typography

I need to mix English text with and Japanese kanjis in the same text (paragrah).
I found on W3C (https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/WD-i18n-format-19990127/) the CSS property layout-grid-type, which when set to 'fixed' seems to do exactly what I need.
I tried the below code sample but I cannot get it work as expected, [like this for example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYp7w.png).
All characters (roman, kanjis and even symbols) must have the same bounding box width (whatever the spacing in between).

```
<head>
    <style>
        .example {
            layout-grid-type: fixed;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="example">layout-grid-typeこ子: fixed</div>
</body>
```

What am I misisng here ?
Thank you.

[edit] I realized the W3C doc above was a draft, seems was not released as it. Any aternative then for that presentation style ?

Comment: I think I found the alternative: text-transform: full-width is the solution for characters. However, it does not preserve spaces as pre does...

Comment: Well, I found that white-space: pre; would help for spaces ! Almost all fixed.
Last issue remaining is symbols which are not text are not impacted by text-transform. For example this arrow "↑" appears as narrow as it is here. I need it as wide as all other characters...

Comment: See this : https://blog.prototypr.io/better-together-displaying-japanese-and-english-text-on-the-web-538a704399be

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Kevin, the blog clarified it all !

This header is enough to get is all addressed : all chars and symbols have the same width now.

[EDIT]: This works in [Firefox only](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-transform) ! Chars width is not same in other browsers...
Back to original question :(

```
<!doctype HTML> 
<html lang="ja-jp" /> 
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <style>
        .example {
            text-transform: full-width;
            white-space: pre;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="example">layo&uarr;t-grid-typeこ子: fixed</div>
    <div class="example">layo ut-grid-typeこ子: fixed</div>
    <div class="example">123456789012345678901234567890</div>
    <div class="example">    56789012345678901234567890</div>
    <div class="example">&uarr;&uarr;&larr;&rarr;&darr;↑↑56789012345678901234567890</div>
    <div class="example">↑↑↑↑56789012345678901234567890</div>
</body>
```